# Windows NIC showing No Internet Access for entire network but no issues?

Tags: windows

I have a strange problem. My entire windows network NIC cards (200 computers) are reporting In windows under local area connection status that there is no internet access (causing the famous yellow windows exclamation).

However there are no issues with network connectivity internal or going out to web. Everything works. In fact there are no issues with any of the dns servers/domain/firewall/switches or anything.

Has anyone ever experienced this problem?

Comment: Sure. It's a fairly common occurrence. NCSI doesn't always work reliably. You can disable it via the Registry (or via a Registry modification in a GPO) or you can host your own internal NCSI server, or you can choose to ignore it. - http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2012/12/20/the-network-connection-status-icon.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. The Cisco ASA CX module (cant wait to dump it for firepower) falsely blocked http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt as a possible malware threat.

This occurred this morning without much reason or explanation. Unfortunately for some reason NCSI could not use the passive probe process to figure out it was actually connected to the internet.

Unblocking the URL fixed the issue.

Special thanks to @joeqwerty for linking me the Microsoft NCSI article.